# Normal map showing seams

Tags: normal-map

Using the normal map gives me this seam effect. Idk why this happens. The normal map is on OpenGL.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe pack your image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I fixed it. No idea what it was. Maybe changing the normal on OpenGL in my 2 try worked. Idk

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I tried a lot of things, so idk what made it work..... I would say put the normal on OpenGL if ou're having a similar error.